# Sample size via confidence intervals

Tags: r, sample-size

I'm looking for a R package to compute sample size for the differences of two proportions via confidence inetrval (CI). Note that there are several methods to compute CI for the difference in proportions, and for some of these methods one can compute sample size with pencil and paper, but I was wondering if there is package invoving several of these methods.

Thanks

Comment: A reasonable starting place to look would be the [CRAN Experimental Design Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html). Don't know if it actually does hold what you need, though.

Answer (score 1):

[power.prop.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/power.prop.test.html)?